# Why does the Doctor make the pop sound in Heaven Sent?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

In "Heaven Sent", at the beginning

> when he is in the bedroom and the thing lurches up to him, he says "when i was a very little boy there was an old lady that died "*pop*" they covered her in veils, but it was a hot sunny day and the flies came, so who's been stealing my nightmares" why make the pop sound?.

Is it a saying or an old time gesture of some sort? It just seems strange to be put in for no reason. I want to know if there is something I'm just not getting.

Comment: I assumed it was a simple reference to her dying (as in "*he [popped off](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pop+off) at the age of 80*" or "*she [popped her clogs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pop_one%27s_clogs)*").

Answer (score 5):

I think that the sound is put in to indicate the suddenness of the event in his mind. It's the same way that people will say things like "I was confused and then *POW* it hit me."

Comment: yeah i thought that but then today someone asked me and i said that but then you know when u have a little self doubt thinking " was i right? " or could it be a olden gesture of some sort

Comment: @daniel: Not that I could find. :) Do you find the answer acceptable?